# Actuator not working when management.port and management.context-path is provided

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have added a different port and context-path for spring boot actuator in my application properties but i am getting the following response when i access

> localhost:9091/app/actuator/health

```
{
    "payload": {
        "timestamp": "2019-01-04T13:10:42Z",
        "status": 500,
        "error": "Internal Server Error",
        "exception": "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException",
        "message": "Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.",
        "path": "/app/actuator/health"
    }
}
```

here's my configuration

```
server:
  port: 9090
  contextPath: /app
...
management:
  port: 9091
  ssl.enabled: false
  security:
    roles: ACTUATOR_GET
  context-path: /app/actuator
endpoints:
  hypermedia:
    enabled: true
...
```

What am i doing wrong ?

i am using spring-boot 1.5

Comment: did you customize /health result within your code? if so can you post any relevant snippet related to it?

Comment: may be these answers help you, having the same error msg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875098/protecting-rest-api-with-oauth2-error-creating-bean-with-name-scopedtarget-oau in short: Add a RequestContextListener to your config.

Comment: I think it's a kind of security problem , check the console of your service, perhaps it a kind of autorization of the actuator endpoints with oauth2 !? do you implement Oauth ? because your config is correct and the url access will be `http://host:9091/app/actuator/health`

Comment: Issue solved. The exception was being originated from a custom `OncePerRequestFilter` that implemented `RememberMeServices`. 

In that filter I was clearing OAuthContext by doing `restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().setAccessToken(null);`

- which was causing `BeanCreationException`. I have put this statement in a try-catch block and the actuator is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. The exception was being originated from a custom `OncePerRequestFilter` that implemented `RememberMeServices`. In that filter I was clearing `OAuthContext` by doing `restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().setAccessToken(null);` - which was causing `BeanCreationException`. I have put this statement in a `try-catch` block and the actuator is working fine now.