# How to overcome intermittent Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread for OauthClientContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm attempting to implement OpenId Connect sign-on in a Spring Boot 1.3.0 application with Spring Security 3.2.5 on Spring Framework 4.2.3. The implementation is very similar to this question: [Protecting REST API with OAuth2: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext': Scope 'session' is not active](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35875098/1146608), except that I've implemented the suggested bean for the `RequestContextFilter`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class OpenIdConnectConfig {
    @Value("${oidc.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${oidc.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${oidc.accessTokenUrl}")
    private String accessTokenUri;

    @Value("${oidc.userAuthorizationUri}")
    private String userAuthorizationUri;

    @Value("${oidc.redirectUri}")
    private String redirectUri;

    @Value("#{'${oidc.scopes}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> oidcScopes;

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails openIdResourceDetails() {
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        details.setClientId(clientId);
        details.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        details.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        details.setUserAuthorizationUri(userAuthorizationUri);
        details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
        details.setScope(oidcScopes);
        details.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(redirectUri);
        details.setUseCurrentUri(false);
        return details;
    }

    @Bean(name = "my.company.ui.security.OpenIdRestTemplate")
    // ToDo: fix org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread
    public OAuth2RestTemplate OpenIdRestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(openIdResourceDetails(), clientContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }
}
```

The exception stack trace is likewise similar

```
Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext':
  Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider 
  defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it
  from a singleton; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound
  request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an
  actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally 
  receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
  and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside 
  of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use 
  RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:187)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.getAccessToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:169)
    at my.company.ui.security.OpenIdConnectFilter.attemptAuthentication(OpenIdConnectFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at my.company.ui.security.OpenIdConnectFilter.doFilter(OpenIdConnectFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at my.company.ui.security.UserCookieFilter.doFilter(UserCookieFilter.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at my.company.server.filter.UncaughtExceptionRequestFilter.doFilter(UncaughtExceptionRequestFilter.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at com.rmn.commons.web.metrics.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    ... 48 more
Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:187)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.getAccessToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:169)
    at my.company.ui.security.OpenIdConnectFilter.attemptAuthentication(OpenIdConnectFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at my.company.ui.security.OpenIdConnectFilter.doFilter(OpenIdConnectFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at my.company.ui.security.UserCookieFilter.doFilter(UserCookieFilter.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at my.company.server.filter.UncaughtExceptionRequestFilter.doFilter(UncaughtExceptionRequestFilter.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at com.rmn.commons.web.metrics.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Powered by Jetty://
```

You can clearly see that the filter call is part of the Spring Security `FilterChainProxy`, so I don't know what to make of the error message's suggestion that "your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet". Also, I have tried adding a bean for the suggested alternative `RequestContextFilter` and the same exception is thrown.

The filter that performs the authentication (some exception handling and user processing code removed):

```
public class OpenIdConnectFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public OpenIdConnectFilter(
            RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher,
            AuthenticationService authenticationService
    ) {
        super(requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher);
        setAuthenticationManager(new NoopAuthenticationManager());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("RedundantThrows") // Matching overridden method
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        // Required parameters (one-time access code, state) are retrieved from the context
        OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken = restTemplate.getAccessToken();

        // Process the token, get the user details, return an Authentication object.
    }

    public void setRestTemplate(OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;

    }

    private static class NoopAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No authentication should be done with this AuthenticationManager");
        }

    }


    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OpenIdConnectFilter.class);

    @Value("${oidc.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${oidc.issuer}")
    private String issuer;

    @Value("${oidc.jwt.jwk.url}")
    private String jwkUrl;

    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;
}
```

And the Security Config that sets up the Spring Security FilterProxyChain:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {

        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .expressionHandler(securityExpressionHandler)
                .antMatchers("/asset/**").access("permitAll")
                .antMatchers("/ws/ssoEnabled").access("permitAll")
                .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_TOKEN_ACCESS')")
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(ajaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
            // Handles unauthenticated requests, catching UserRedirectRequiredExceptions and redirecting to OAuth provider
            .addFilterAfter(new OAuth2ClientContextFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
            // Handles the oauth callback, exchanging the one-time code for a durable token
            .addFilterAfter(openIdConnectFilter, OAuth2ClientContextFilter.class)
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/logincheck")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(ajaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(ajaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
                // Even though this key has been added directly to the rememberMeServices instance, the RememberMeConfigurer
                // can instantiate a new RememberMeServices with a made-up key if the same key is not provided.
                .key("the key value")
        ;

        // We do not configure a bean for the SessionAuthenticationStrategy. We want to use the Spring default strategy,
        // which is configured by the above builder chain. In order to share the correct, configured instance with our
        // custom OpenIdConnectFilter, we first tell the builder to perform the configuration (normally this would be
        // done long after this method returns)...
        http.getConfigurer(SessionManagementConfigurer.class).init(http);
        // ... then we get the shared object by interface (SessionAuthenticationStrategy) class name...
        final SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy = http.getSharedObject(SessionAuthenticationStrategy.class);
        // ... then set it in our custom filter.
        openIdConnectFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy);
    }
}
```

One final wrinkle: I was getting this error while running on my machine. Then, adding the `RequestContextListener` resolved it. When deploying it to our test environment, the exception message resurfaces. However, after a few hours or days, sometimes after the CI/CD pipeline re-deploys the same version, the problem resolves itself and the OpenID integration works as expected until we make the next change, bugfix or improvement, then it usually reoccurs for a similar short interval.

---

Questions:

1. Is `DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet` a factor at all when running in Spring Boot?
2. How do you determine if you should use a [`RequestContextFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html) or [`RequestContextListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html)? Is there an actual difference? The (linked) documentation isn't much help here, in my opinion.

   > Servlet listener that exposes the request to the current thread, through both LocaleContextHolder and RequestContextHolder. To be registered as listener in web.xml.
   >
   > Alternatively, Spring's RequestContextFilter and Spring's DispatcherServlet also expose the same request context to the current thread. In contrast to this listener, advanced options are available there (e.g. "threadContextInheritable").
   >
   > This listener is mainly for use with third-party servlets, e.g. the JSF FacesServlet. Within Spring's own web support, DispatcherServlet's processing is perfectly sufficient.
3. Where should the Beans for the RequestContextFilter/Listener be defined in a Spring Boot app? We don't have a `web.xml`. (My understanding is that `web.xml` is only for Spring MVC - please correct me if that is wrong.)
4. What could possibly be causing the context to be found *sometimes*? Why is it that our app can work after enduring failure for a little while?

Comment: Is this stack trace for when you register the listener? Where do you actually register these filters/listeners? What is the order of your listeners? (Note: there **is** support for web.xml in Boot as well, it's just optional: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-vs-java-config)

Comment: Note: if you register the filter instead of the listener, you'd see (or not, depending on filter order) it in the stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace is from any request that hits the login filter. I have added the additional code for the filter and the configuration. When you say "register" is there anything additional that needs to be done beyond declaring a `@Bean`? Because that's all the examples and similar SO questions I've found show. Thank you for the tip on web.xml, I will read over that article more closely, though it doesn't seem to mention Spring Boot. The stack trace does not seem to contain any line from the filter or listener.

Comment: It shouldn't really contain lines from the listener(if that is registered), but should contain lines from filter (if that is registered). I think you don't actually need a listener bean (nevermind the answer), but you do need to use either the listener or the filter inside `configure` - and the filter should trigger before OAuth one.

Comment: The stack trace does not contain any lines from `RequestContextFilter`; it also appears that every stack trace occurrence of `OncePerRequestFilter` (parent class) is accounted for by another filter's `doFilterInternal` method call immediately after. I added an explicit `.addFilterAfter(requestContextFilter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)` line to the SecurityConfig `configure` method and debugged: I can see that the `RequestContextFilter` is executed by Spring boot once and then again by Spring Security in the FilterChainProxy - at least when running locally. Will try it deployed next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigating this further, I found that the `RequestContextFilter` was definitely being executed before the `Oauth2ClientContextFilter` and `OpenIdConnectFilter` when running locally. I decide to take a chance on M. Prokhorov's suggestion from the comments and register the `RequestContextFilter` into Spring Security's filters anyways; it extends the `OncePerRequestFilter` preventing it from executing more than once anyways.

All said and done, I went with the following modifications:

Removed the declaration of the `RequestContextLister` bean from the OpenIdConnectConfig. This was registered elsewhere in the application, in a parent module that I verified was getting configuration-scanned.

```
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<RequestContextListener> requestContextListener() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>(new RequestContextListener());
}
```

---

Moved the `Oauth2ClientContextFilter` into a bean declaration. It doesn't seem like there's anything in this filter that relies on being populated as a Spring bean – in testing, the client configuration was attached to the `UserRedirectRequiredException` that this filter processes *before* the `OAuth2RestTemplate` (which does have the client configuration `OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails` injected into it by Spring) throws it. However, it felt like defensive programming in case a future version of Spring changes the interplay between this filter, the exceptions it handles, and the OAuth client details.

---

Adding the filter to the `HttpSecurity` object in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure()` call in `SecurityConfig.java`. The final code for that class looked like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {

        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .expressionHandler(securityExpressionHandler)
                .antMatchers("/asset/**").access("permitAll")
                .antMatchers("/ws/ssoEnabled").access("permitAll")
                .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_TOKEN_ACCESS')")
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(ajaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()

            // OAuth filters
            // Explicitly add a RequestContextFilter ahead of the Oauth filters to facilitate retrieval of a session-scoped oauth2ClientContext object
            .addFilterAfter(requestContextFilter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
            // Handles unauthenticated requests, catching UserRedirectRequiredExceptions and redirecting to OAuth provider
            .addFilterAfter(oAuth2ClientContextFilter, RequestContextFilter.class)
            // Handles the oauth callback, exchanging the one-time code for a durable token
            .addFilterAfter(openIdConnectFilter, OAuth2ClientContextFilter.class)

            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/logincheck")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(ajaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(ajaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
                // Even though this key has been added directly to the rememberMeServices instance, the RememberMeConfigurer
                // can instantiate a new RememberMeServices with a made-up key if the same key is not provided.
                .key("the key value")
        ;

        // We do not configure a bean for the SessionAuthenticationStrategy. We want to use the Spring default strategy,
        // which is configured by the above builder chain. In order to share the correct, configured instance with our
        // custom OpenIdConnectFilter, we first tell the builder to perform the configuration (normally this would be
        // done long after this method returns)...
        http.getConfigurer(SessionManagementConfigurer.class).init(http);
        // ... then we get the shared object by interface (SessionAuthenticationStrategy) class name...
        final SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy = http.getSharedObject(SessionAuthenticationStrategy.class);
        // ... then set it in our custom filter.
        openIdConnectFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class ContextAwareCallable<T> implements Callable<T> {

    private Callable<T> task;
    private RequestAttributes context;

    public ContextAwareCallable(Callable<T> task, RequestAttributes context) {
        this.task = task;
        this.context = cloneRequestAttributes(context);
    }

    @Override
    public T call() throws Exception {
        if (context != null) {
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context);

        }
        try {
            return task.call();
        } finally {
            RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
        }
    }

    private RequestAttributes cloneRequestAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes) {
        RequestAttributes clonedRequestAttribute = null;
        try {
            clonedRequestAttribute =
                    new ServletRequestAttributes(((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest(),
                    ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getResponse());
            if (requestAttributes.getAttributeNames(RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST).length > 0) {
                for (String name : requestAttributes.getAttributeNames(RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST)) {
                    clonedRequestAttribute.setAttribute(name,
                            requestAttributes.getAttribute(name, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST),
                            RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
                }
            }
            return clonedRequestAttribute;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return requestAttributes;
        }
    }
}
```

Then Create Executor

```
public class ContextAwarePoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {

    @Override
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submit(new ContextAwareCallable(task, RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()));
    }

    @Override
    public <T> ListenableFuture<T> submitListenable(Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submitListenable(new ContextAwareCallable(task, RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()));
    }
```